# how to make an object of child class in parent class

Tags: c++, oop, ooad

i am writing a piece of code in c++, but really unable to sort one problem out, i am trying to make an object of child class in parent class, but this gives me an error where I inherit the parent class "undefined base class" any way out?

```
#include "Item.h"
#include "Borrower.h"
#include "Librarian.h"
#include "Clerk.h"
class lib_management_system
{
protected:
    item *items_array;
    borrower *borrower_array;
    librarian *librarian_array;
    clerk *clerk_array;
    int items_count;
    int borrower_count;
    int clerk_count;
    int librarian_count;
//public members
};
```

where item, borrower, librarian and clerk are child classes of this parent class

Comment: thanks for replying, what about making the object of current child class in another class and inheriting parent from that class, would it work

Comment: Show code snippets trying to explain what you want to do, please .

Comment: Wait, you're saying an "item" is a lib_management_system?  And a clerk IS A lib_management_system?  Or are you trying to make a lib_management_system OWN A item?  It's not clear why you would need the item, etc to inherit from the lib_management_system....

Comment: look, library_managment_system has every thing all items,borrowers,librarians and some functions like search_an_item.Now as borrower is a seperate class (whose private members are fname,lname) if borrower wants to search an item???? so thats why i made borrower the child of library_management_system.

Comment: But that's not how inheritance works.  The item class, when it is a child, will have all of its own item, borrower, librarian, and clerk's.  Each instance of a class gets its own stuff.  You can make data exist once and only once per class by making it static, but that doesn't make your proposed pattern a good one.  I'd significantly rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is often a sign of bad design...

The only think you can do and **I would even advice AGAINST this**, unless in some resource management case, maybe):

```
// Forward declaration
class Child;

class Parent
{
 public:
  // Parent code
  // ...


  Child* _child;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
};
```